# Probability for *given* questions

Tags: probability, algebra-precalculus

I have a question for probability. In probability there something called a *given* which can be represented by | which I will use in this submission.
For example the question: P(B|A) would utilise the formula P(A and B) / P(A). This could be used for a dataset and you would find the answer. I assumed that in the formula for P(B|A), both events divide by the second event would eventually lead to your answer, but this is incorrect. For example my question would be P(A and B|A or B). I have tried to find an answer or a formula to fulfil this question yet I am unable to find one.

If you could please provide me and answer with your own dataset that would be very much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: This is called conditional probability.

Comment: P(A and B|A or B) is confusing.  Please rewrite with parentheses to clarify.

Comment: @herbsteinberg There is no ambiguity.  Everything to the left of the bar inside the parentesis is the event, while the condition is everything to the right .

Answer (score 2):

I will use $A \cap B$ to denote "A and B" and $A \cup B$ to denote "A or B." Then,

$$P(A \cap B \mid A \cup B) = \frac{P((A \cap B) \cap (A \cup B))}{P(A \cup B)}.$$

Note that the numerator of the fraction is the statement "A and B and A or B," which is true only when "A and B" occurs. So, we can rewrite it as

$$\frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(A \cup B)}.$$

Comment: Hi Ekesh, Thank you for your answer. To use your formulae I constructed a simple Venn Diagram. A = 5, B = 2, A ∩ B = 8. When using your formulae, would you do 8/15 * 15/15 to find A ∩ B? The events are dependent however so what other alternative would there be get the answer?